# How to separate data from subdomains in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to split my data from different subdomains in Google Analytics. I know it's possible to do it using different profiles + filters, but when you have a ton of subdomains, it's almost impossible to maintain that setup. Is there another way?

Currently I'm using this solution http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to figure this out myself a while ago and [wrote a blog post about it](https://blog.ostermiller.org/analytics-subdomain/).  You *can* get a comparison of your subdomains without applying any filters or advanced segment, but the functionality is buried and non-intuitive.

1. Navigate to “Content”-> “Site Content” -> “All Pages”. 
   [image: Google Analytics All Pages Navigation]
2. Change the primary dimension to “Other” -> “Content” -> “Hostname”.  
   [image: Google Analytics Primary Dimension Host name]
    At this point the data table will show your best host names but the graph will still show total page views.
3. If you have more than 10 sub-domains, you may want to show more of them at once.  Only the number shown will be included in the graph. 
   [image: Google Analytics Show Rows]
4. Select the icon for “Motion Chart” above the graph on the right hand side instead of the currently selected icon for “Line Chart”.  ”Motion chart” is the icon with the three circles on it. (Don’t ask me why the line chart I want is under “motion chart” rather than “line chart.”) 
   [image]
5. Use the tabs on the top right of the graph and select the one with the line on it.  You will get the graph that you are looking for. 
   [image]
    Each of the lines on that graph represents a sub-domain so you can quickly compare how your sub-domains are doing over time.  The graph is interactive so you can mouse over it to see data and use the check boxes to the right to highlight rows.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of doing it this way is it gives you a roll up account. If you create separate accounts for each, it will make it a nightmare to get website totals.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adrian.  It's far less of a hassle to keep everything in one account if you want to do any aggregate reporting.  If you simply set the primary dimension to Hostname, you don't even need to set an Advanced Segment or use an Advanced filter for hostname.  Both of these can also be used if you want to dice data using two dimensions.