# Segment subdomains with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

So, when a website has multiple subdomains:

```
www.example.com
foo.example.com
bar.example.com
```

What is the best way to use Google Analytics to segment the data? I would prefer have access to 'All Data', 'Data from foo.example.com', and 'Data from bar.example.com'.

I tried setting up 3 different views, and setting a filter on the foo/bar views that says:

```
Include only traffic from the ISP domain that are equal to foo.example.com.
```

However, I am not seeing any data collected into that View. I do, however, see all data in the  'All Data' view, but I can't figure out how to segment the data. I am including the `analytics.js` in the `application.haml` layout, which is always loaded in this app.

Comment: You can also see some stats for each subdomain without applying any filters: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42299/how-to-separate-data-from-subdomains-in-google-analytics

Answer (score 1):

You're so close, instead of using `traffic from ISP domain` use `traffic to the hostname`.

[image: ga filter]

To view if it is working, check out your real-time overview report.

Comment: Wow, that's embarassing. After reading that so many times I just skipped over the ISP part lol. Thanks! I'll make sure it works how I want and accept your answer :)